# Spark cache RDD don't show up on Spark History WebUI - Storage

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, cloudera-cdh

I am using `Spark-1.4.1` in `CDH-5.4.4`.

I use `rdd.cache()` function but it show nothing in `Storage tab` on `Spark History WebUI`

Does anyone has the same issues? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your RDD will only be cached once its been evaluated, the most common way to force evaluation (and therefor populate the cache) is to call `count` e.g:

```
rdd.cache() // Nothing in storage page yet & nothing cached
rdd.count() // RDD evaluated, cached & in storage page.
```

Comment: I try `rdd.count()` then it works. I used this rdd to join with other rdd but It still not show up on storage page. Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: So just to make sure I understand, after the count() it shows up and then you join it with another rdd and that isn't showing up? If you want that to show up you would also need to `cache`/`persist` along with force evaluation.

Comment: Oh no! I am talking about my situation when I post this question. I use `rdd.cache()` then join it with another rdd. I save result to parquet. In my case, it doesn't show up.
I have try `rdd.cache()` and `rdd.count()`. It works perfect!

Comment: ok, cool :) you could try running toDebugString on the joined RDD to see whats going on

Answer (score 9):

Apart from forcing RDD evaluation (with an action, like `count`), I also had to enable Spark option:

```
spark.eventLog.logBlockUpdates.enabled=true
```

I'm using Spark 2.3.0, by the way.

Comment: This is the crucial part that works for me! Thank you!