# spark history server does not show RDD even if it is persisted

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am running spark shell in spark version 2.0.2. Here is my program,

```
var myrdd = sc.parallelize(Array.range(1, 10))
myrdd.setName("test")
myrdd.cache
myrdd.collect
```

But I am still not able to see any RDD info in "storage" tab in spark history server.

I looked at [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/117/why-is-my-rdd-not-showing-up-in-the-storage-tab-of.html) but it is not helping as I have exact similar program mentioned there. Can anyone help?

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715698/spark-cache-rdd-dont-show-up-on-spark-history-webui-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, there is difference in spark history server and spark UI. Spark UI is only available while the spark context is alive. Spark history server is available even after the spark program is completed. Spark history server loads the data from event log file which captures various events during spark program lifecycle. But event log does not capture the RDD related events(in order to avoid increasing the event log file size) and hence even if there is "Storage" tab in spark history server, it does not show any RDD information because RDD related data is not stored in event logs.

Answer (score 0):

Spark history server shows data once context is stopped.So automatically all cache will be lost.We will not have cache information.