# Blank storage tab in Spark history server

Tags: apache-spark

When we persist an RDD and take an action on it, the Spark UI's Storage tab would show some information about that RDD. However, once the job is finished, the storage tab in Spark's history server is a blank page. This seems to be an issue in Spark ([SPARK-16859](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16859?jql=text%20~%20%22storage%20tab%20history%20server%22)). I would like to know if this issue is still true.

Comment: You are right, after Spark 1.6 every time my jobs are finished I lose everything in the storage tab. I thought it would have been fixed in later versions but I am using Spark 2.2 and still the same.

Comment: **@Xiangyu**, **@Maziyar** I'm seeing *blank* `Storage` tab even when my `Spark` job is running. And I've even put a `df.cache.count()` action so that it is guaranteed that *significant amount of* memory will be used. I'm using `Spark 2.2.1` on `EMR 5.12.0`

Comment: @y2k-shubham, I am still suffering with the same issue with Spark 2.4.0 on EMR 5.20.1. Do you have any suggestion as a work-around this problem?

Comment: **@Roxana** While it's been a while since I last worked on `Spark`, from the bits that I remember, it was a **Memory tuning problem**. I never had a very clear understanding of the issue, but my guess is that without turning the knobs such as *G1GC*, and other [memory-related confs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties), my `Executor`s were just *sulking for resources* and they never got a chance to register their presence of UI (hence blank storage). After I supplied appropriate memory tuning confs, the problem vanished (I didn't even realize when)

Comment: Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715698/spark-cache-rdd-dont-show-up-on-spark-history-webui-storage